# Asp.Net Regex C# replace function not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, code-behind

I'm trying to format emojis in my html page with a regex replace code in c#, but the code work fine in regex testers but not working in C#.

Pattern

```
/&(?:\#(?:(?<dec>[0-9]+)|[Xx](?<hex>[0-9A-Fa-f]+))|(?<named>[A-Za-z0-9]+));/
```

Value

```
teste &#128512;&#128513;&#128514;
```

Result

```
teste <span class='emoji'>&#128512;</span><span class='emoji'>&#128513;</span><span class='emoji'>&#128514;</span>
```

You can test in
https://rgxdb.com/try

My C# code

```
public static string FormatTextEmoji(string pText)
{
    //Armazena o retorno
    string lReturn = pText;
    //Seta a expressão
    string lExpression = @"/&(?:\#(?:(?<dec>[0-9]+)|[Xx](?<hex>[0-9A-Fa-f]+))|(?<named>[A-Za-z0-9]+));/";
    //Ignora o case
    Regex lRegex = new Regex(lExpression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    //Seta a notícia com os links
    lReturn = lRegex.Replace(lReturn, "<span class=\"emoji\">$1</span>");
    //Retorna o valor
    return lReturn;
}
```

I have another Regex Replace that working fine, i tried a lot of modifications but no success.

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Remove first and last ``/``

Comment: I'd simplify the expression to: \&[\#A-Za-z0-9]+;

Comment: Wiktor your answer solve part of the problem, the match now is working but the result lost &#; 

Result
"teste <span class='emoji'>128512</span><span class='emoji'>128513</span><span class='emoji'>128514</span>"

And i need the result as: 

teste <span class='emoji'>&#128512;</span><span class='emoji'>&#128513;</span><span class='emoji'>&#128514;</span>

Comment: Colin your sugestion does not result in replace that i need, the result shows  <span class='emoji'>$1</span> and i need the result as <span class='emoji'>&#128512;</span>, I need to transform &#128512; into <span class='emoji'>&#128512;</span>